# Is there anyway to change the rotation mode of multiple bones at once?

Tags: modeling, interface

I am tired of manually switching from Quaternion rotation mode to XYZ euler mode for every bone. Is there anyway to accelerate this process? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a script that will change **all** the [pose bone rotation mode](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html?highlight=rotation_mode#bpy.types.PoseBone.rotation_mode) to the value set for `to_mode` in this case 'XYZ' for XYZ Euler Rotation on the active (context) object.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

to_mode = 'XYZ'
arm = context.object

for pb in arm.pose.bones:
    pb.rotation_mode = to_mode
```

Possibly more useful to use `context.selected_pose_bones` which will set the mode only for those pose bones selected.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

to_mode = 'XYZ'

for pb in context.selected_pose_bones:
    pb.rotation_mode = to_mode
```