# How to change default bone rotation from Quaternion (WXYZ) to Euler (XYZ)?

Tags: armature, bones, quaternion

For all the bone of an armature in pose mode, in the item/transform menu and on object properties/transform, the default mode is alway Quaternion (WXYZ).

How can I change that to Euler XYZ for all existing and future bones?

Comment: For changing existing bones https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72727/is-there-anyway-to-change-the-rotation-mode-of-multiple-bones-at-once